# matrix representation of polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Here is a polynomial $p(x,y) = (ax + by)^2$, it can be written like this $$p(x,y) = \left(\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
\end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
\end{array} \right]\right)^2$$
and I know that it can also be written as something like $v^TMv$, here $v = [x,y]^T$, and $$M = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
a^2 & ab \\
ab & b^2\\
\end{array} \right]$$. But how could I find out $M$, any technique?

Furthermore, here $p(x,y)$ has degree $2$, and it can be represented with the multiplication of matrix and vector, what if the degree is $3,4...$?

Comment: Any polynomial $\sum c_{ij}x_ix_j$ of degree 2 is $v^tAv$ for $v=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, and entry $a_{ij}$ of $A$ given by $(c_{ij}+c_{ji})/2$.

Comment: Can you give an example for which you mean degree 3,4 polynomial??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
\end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
x & y \\
\end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c}
a\\
b
\end{array} \right]$$
Then $M= \left[ \begin{array}{c}
a & b
\end{array}\right]  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
a\\
b
\end{array}\right]$

Letting $v=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array} \right]$ and $A=\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
\end{array} \right]$ we use the first line to note that $Av=v^TA^T$., and hence that $$(Av)^2 = (Av)^T(Av) = v^TA^TAv = v^T(A^TA)v$$

So $M=A^TA$.

Comment: I don't quite get it, how?

Comment: Edited to clarify somewhat.

Comment: Yes, got it, ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $M=(m_{ij})$, then $$v^TMv=\sum_{i,j}m_{ij}v_iv_j$$ Then compare the coefficients of $v_iv_j\ \forall i,j$ of both sides of the equation to get $m_{ij}$.

Comment: Also, you can write polynomials of higher order than $2$ using higher order tensors.